# Manage client connection status with multiple SocketIO servers

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I have an application that will send an event from the server side to the client side if the client has been connected and online.

I have 3 NodeJS servers that running on AWS ECS.
But when the traffic is low, the ECS scales off from 3 instances to 2 instances, which means 1 instance will be shut down.

The problem is that 2 other instances don't know that all connected clients to the third instance are disconnected.
If there is a client doesn't reconnect again, the status will be mismatched.

Are there any solutions, thank you in advance.